# Scala calling super from a base class that extends a java class

Tags: java, scala, constructor, base-class

a Scala class inherits JFrame class

```
class App extends JFrame {
  public App {
    //how to call this super method
    super("Hello world");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax is:

```
class App extends JFrame("Hello world") {
  // your code
}
```